# Microprofile OpenAPI Swagger UI - How to hide schema field properties?

Tags: java, swagger-ui, openapi, microprofile

I'm using Swagger with Microprofile 4.1 and OpenAPI 3.0 to document my Jakarta REST api.
I have a simple Entity class and I want to add the "example" property to the fields of the Schema.

Here my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.microprofile-ext.openapi-ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here the code for the id field:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
@Schema(example="123")
private Integer id;
```

I obtain the following result:

[image]

Why I see the others properties? I want to see only the type and the example